# Error: Trying to get property 'num_rows' of non-object

Tags: php

Alguien que me pueda ayudar con lo siguiente, estoy realizando un carrito de compras y al querer cargar la tabla de mis productos me arroja un error. Aqui anexo la parte de mi codigo donde se muestra el error.

```
<div class="panel-body">
<h1>Mis Productos</h1>
<a href="VerCarta.php" class="cart-link" title="Ver Carta"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></i></a>
<div id="products" class="row list-group">
    <?php
    //get rows query
    $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM mis_productos ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10");
    if($query ->num_rows>0){ //MI ERROR ESTA AQUI
        while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
    ?>
    <div class="item col-lg-4">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <div class="caption">
                <h4 class="list-group-item-heading"><?php echo $row["name"]; ?></h4>
                <p class="list-group-item-text"><?php echo $row["description"]; ?></p>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <p class="lead"><?php echo '$'.$row["price"].' USD'; ?></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <a class="btn btn-success" href="AccionCarta.php?action=addToCart&id=<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>">Agregar a la Carta</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php } }else{ ?>
    <p>Producto(s) no existe.....</p>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola amigo solo debes realizar una validación previa antes de la siguiente línea:

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
```

Te quedará así:

```
if (!empty($result)) {
    if($result->num_rows > 0){
```

Con esto evaluas que la variable **$result** no este vacia.

> Esto es necesario ya que cuando no obtienes registros te genera el
>   error

Luego verificas que el número de registros sea mayor a 0.